# Install Ubuntu on second hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I am wondering how I can install Ubuntu onto my second hard drive in my Toshiba Qosmio?? My main drive is my SSD that runs my normal Windows OS, but I installed a second hard drive in my second hard drive bay and would like to install and run Ubuntu from that second drive?? That way I can choose which drive to boot from whether it's my main drive using Windows or my second drive using Ubuntu??

Comment: OK, what exactly is stopping you? Installing in a different drive is as trivial as installing in the same drive.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your Ubuntu CD in CD/DVD rider and start installation. Select the second hard drive for installation. It should be named something like 'sdb1' , because main hard drive is generally named sda1.
The process is easy, just give it a try.
If any difficulty arises post it here again. We will be happy to help.

Comment: Okay, so I was able to figure it all out. It's very slow on an HDD, if I switch the installation to an SSD it should improve the speed/performance right? I have an extra SSD I can spare into the extra bay so I would assume it should work?

Comment: SSD should work faster than HDD. However it also depends on your ram and processor speed.

Comment: I already have an SSD installed into the same PC for my Windows system. Have 8GB Ram and I'm unsure of my processor speed but I know my processor is an Intel Core I7. I know it can handle the SSD, but now trying to figure out how to get Ubuntu installed onto it.